# How get the Qt PostgreSQL plugin in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

Good day.
I wrote a small program to understand how Qt c ++ and SQL works.
She writes to me:

```
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
```

After reading the Internet, I found out that I needed a SQL plugin, I found this instruction https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql (Why are plugins not working out of the box? It doesn't matter.)
Ok. I go to the folder ~/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
Do "qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql"
Ok

```
Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/usr'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

Do "make sub-psql"
And I get

```
cd psql/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/psql.pro PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql ) && make -f Makefile
make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql»
g++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -std=c++1z -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-init-list-lifetime -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -isystem /usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qsql_psql.o qsql_psql.cpp
qsql_psql.cpp: In constructor ‘QPSQLDriverPrivate::QPSQLDriverPrivate()’:
qsql_psql.cpp:152:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  152 |     QPSQLDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::PostgreSQL) {}
      |                                                                    ^
In file included from qsql_psql.cpp:55:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:66:5: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate()’
   66 |     QSqlDriverPrivate()
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:66:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(const QSqlDriverPrivate&)’
   61 | class QSqlDriverPrivate : public QObjectPrivate
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QSqlDriver::DbmsType’ to ‘const QSqlDriverPrivate&’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriverPrivate&&)’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QSqlDriver::DbmsType’ to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate&&’
make[1]: *** [Makefile:384: .obj/qsql_psql.o] Error 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql»
make: *** [Makefile:45: sub-psql] Error 2
What's happening? I just need to work with SQL, but that's all. If we open the sqldrivers.pro project using QtCreator, and try to compile, we get 3 errors:

/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp:147: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp:147:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  147 |     inline QSQLiteDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::SQLite) {}
      |                                                                         ^
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:152: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:152:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  152 |     QPSQLDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::PostgreSQL) {}
      |                                                                    ^
:-1: Error: [Makefile:845: .obj/qsql_sqlite.o] Error 1
```

How do I get the plugin?
I'm using communiti QtCreator, PostgreSQL 13.1 , Ubuntu 20.04.

If i enter the command "sudo apt install postgresql-client-13"
then the terminal writes "The most recent version of postgresql-client-13 package (13.1-1.pgdg20.04 + 1) is already installed.
postgresql-client-13 is marked as manually installed."

the output after "export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1" is huge, even larger than the code of the program itself.
Here it is, what would you advise to look for there?

I lost hope, what else can I do?

Its log after "export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1"  https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3tnm/Zn2pjp1qr

I installed Qt in the 'home/myname/Qt' folder
But as I see the log now, there is an independent folder /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/
I didn't create it.
Now I run make in the '~/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers' folder
And got new errors:

```
anton@home:~/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers$ make sub-psql
cd psql/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/psql.pro PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql ) && make -f Makefile
make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql»
g++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -std=c++1z -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-init-list-lifetime -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -isystem /usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qsql_psql.o qsql_psql.cpp
qsql_psql.cpp: In constructor ‘QPSQLDriverPrivate::QPSQLDriverPrivate()’:
qsql_psql.cpp:152:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  152 |     QPSQLDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::PostgreSQL) {}
      |                                                                    ^
In file included from qsql_psql.cpp:55:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:66:5: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate()’
   66 |     QSqlDriverPrivate()
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:66:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(const QSqlDriverPrivate&)’
   61 | class QSqlDriverPrivate : public QObjectPrivate
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QSqlDriver::DbmsType’ to ‘const QSqlDriverPrivate&’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note: candidate: ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriverPrivate&&)’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.12.8/QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QSqlDriver::DbmsType’ to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate&&’
make[1]: *** [Makefile:384: .obj/qsql_psql.o] Ошибка 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql»
make: *** [Makefile:45: sub-psql] Ошибка 2
```

Another interesting point, if you open the SQLPlagin project in QTCreator, you can see that the sources with errors
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqldrivers.pro
have 3 errors

```
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:152: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'QSqlDriverPrivate' 

:-1: error: [Makefile:845: .obj/qsql_sqlite.o] Error 1

/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:152: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:152:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  152 |     QPSQLDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::PostgreSQL) {}
```

Comment: What version of Qt do you use and how did you install it? I indicate it because in a part of your post it seems that you use the source code of Qt 5.15.2 but according to the log you use you compile with Qt 5.12.8

Comment: I installed it using the online installer, I reinstalled it yesterday - it means the latest version (which is now, I think 6), but I installed all the components. I thought it would help.

Comment: If you are using a different version then the version you provide in your post must match that information but clearly it does not. Please make sure which version you are using and update your post information with the new logs. Don't just assume you're using Qt6 but make sure you are.

Comment: qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu    great ((, but I inserted all the marks in the online installer, there should be all versions.
Or I don't understand something about Qt.

Comment: That is the Qt of the repository of your OS installed with apt-get but you point out that you have used the online installer to install Qt, I see that your comments contradict, please clarify it

Comment: Contradictions? I just installed Ubuntu, then the online installer, put all the checkboxes in the installer and installed it.
That is, it turns out that the system has its own Qt library, which is different from what I installed. At the same time, there is no way to work with SQL, amazing. What should I do to make it work? I really do not understand.

Comment: what is the output of `~/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -v`

Comment: QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib

Comment: then change `qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql` to `~/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql`

Comment: the same result, i described such an error above  'qsql_psql.cpp: In constructor ‘QPSQLDriverPrivate::QPSQLDriverPrivate()’:
qsql_psql.cpp:152:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlDriverPrivate::QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::DbmsType)’
  152 |     QPSQLDriverPrivate() : QSqlDriverPrivate(QSqlDriver::PostgreSQL) {}
      |  '

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the PostgreSQL plugin in Ubuntu, just install the client as Qt provides the plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to compile the plugin (which in general is unnecessary) then you must follow the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
git clone -b 5.15.2 https://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git
cd qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
~/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql
make sub-psql
make install
```

Comment: It works, the compilation went through. It remains to understand where the resulting plugin is and how to add it to Qt.

Comment: @Anton1978 Already added to Qt when `make install` command is run

Comment: strange, still - QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")   , 
I suspect I am having problems with the operating system

Comment: @Anton1978 Are you sure you are using the Qt that is hosted in `~/Qt/5.15.2`? I think you are compiling using the system Qt (Qt 5.12.8), if so then you must install the system plugin using the command `sudo apt-get install '^libqt5sql5-*'`

Comment: I think yes, in Qt Creator the Desktop Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit debugger is selected

Comment: @Anton1978 mmm, you could run your application with command: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 /path/of/build_folder/your_application`

Comment: Link to log https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8mUX/oFK3HvnMn

Comment: That page takes a long time to load, better upload the log in pastebin

Comment: @Anton1978 Could you compile your application in release mode? also recompile the plugin:  `~/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake CONFIG+=debug_and_release -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql`

Comment: i did, no progress, new log https://pastebin.com/HCtaH3j4

Comment: @Anton1978 did u managed to solve your problem? I read whole your posts in https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread2764569-page2.html
now I am in the exact same situation that you were. what did you do at the end?
is there any solution?

Comment: The problem I had was that Qt was taking the wrong version of the sql plugin. The qtchooser utility helped me to solve the problem. Now it's hard to remember what I did, but I forced the required version of Qt and its folder with plugins.